# Stata - output post regression results for hundreds of regressions

Tags: stata

I have run over 100 regressions followed by `dwstat` to get the Durbin Watson statistic.  How can I gather the results in one file?

Comment: Question would be **much improved** by specifying your variables and code you have tried. Please note in any future questions.

Answer (score 2):

Quite an open question but here is one example. You'll have to do more research to get exactly what you want:

```
webuse klein
tsset yr

forvalues i = 1/3 {
    regress consump wagegovt
    estat dwatson

    estadd scalar r_dw = r(dw)

    estimates store myreg`i', title(Model `i')
}

estout * using "D:\some\directory\example.txt", stats(r_dw) replace
```

Run `ssc install estout` to install `estout`. It is a user-written command.

Comment: @user 1542743 You're welcome. Refer, at least, to http://stackoverflow.com/help on asking in StackOverflow. The way in which you ask has great influence on the quality of the answers you get (if you get any at all). Another reference is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

The most flexible way of doing such a thing is using the [post](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?post) command.

Comment: Could you please help with the syntax?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using a postfile:

```
webuse klein
tsset yr

tempname memhold
tempfile filename
postfile `memhold' teststat using `filename'
forvalues i=1/3{
reg  consump wagegovt
estat dwatson
scalar r_dw = r(dw)
post `memhold' (r(dw))
}

postclose `memhold'
clear all 
use `filename'
list
```